# Cell Value Changed Event

Tags: c#, datagridview, cells

When I commit a value to a my cell, this works ok, but when I commit another value to a different cell it changes both the values of these cells. I dont want it to do this, each cell should have its own unique value, how do I go about doing this:

```
       private void retrieveData()
    {
        //returns values, creates and populates dgv
        try
        {
            string company, GetPartCodeV, logname, area;
            dgvDetials.DataSource = null; //resets dgv source to nothing so when refreshing no old data is contained
            dgvDetials.ColumnCount = 0; //removes all columns from dgv so none are repeated when refreshed


            logname = dtArea.Rows[cbArea.SelectedIndex]["logname"].ToString();

            dtArea3 = SQLMethods.GetAreaValues(logname);
            company = dtArea3.Rows[0]["company"].ToString();
            GetPartCodeV = dtArea3.Rows[0]["def_part_type"].ToString();

            DataTable dtGetPartDetails = SQLMethods.PartNo(company, GetPartCodeV); //gets production figures based on selected values

              dgvDetials.DataSource = dtGetPartDetails; //sets dgv source
          //  DataGridViewComboBoxColumn machCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn(); //creates new combobox column for machine
          //  machCol.Name = "machine";
          //  machCol.DataSource = new string[] { "", "1", "2", "3", "4" }; //sets source for combobox column
          //  dgvDetials.Columns.Add(machCol); //adds machine column

            DataGridViewColumn qtyInsp = new DataGridViewColumn(); //creates new textbox column for quantity
            DataGridViewCell qtyCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            qtyInsp.CellTemplate = qtyCell;
            qtyInsp.Name = "qty_insp";
            dgvDetials.Columns.Add(qtyInsp); //inserts new column into dgv

            DataGridViewColumn colScrapCount = new DataGridViewColumn(); //creates new textbow column for scrap count
            DataGridViewCell cellScrapCount = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            colScrapCount.CellTemplate = cellScrapCount;
            colScrapCount.Name = "scrapCount";
            dgvDetials.Columns.Add(colScrapCount); //inserts new column

            DataGridViewColumn colReworkCount = new DataGridViewColumn(); //creates new textbox column for rework count
            DataGridViewCell cellReworkCount = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            colReworkCount.CellTemplate = cellReworkCount;
            colReworkCount.Name = "reworkCount";
            dgvDetials.Columns.Add(colReworkCount); //inserts new column into dgv
            dtArea2 = SQLMethods.GetAreaCode(username,logname);
            area = dtArea2.Rows[0]["area_code"].ToString();

            DataGridViewColumn qtyrecorded = new DataGridViewColumn(); //creates new textbox column for quantity
            DataGridViewCell qtyRecCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            qtyrecorded.CellTemplate = qtyRecCell;
            qtyrecorded.Name = "QtyRecorded";
            dgvDetials.Columns.Add(qtyrecorded); //inserts new column into dgv


            //populate scrap, rework and quantity counts
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvDetials.Rows) //loop through each of the results
            {
                string scrapDate, scrapShift, PartCode;
                scrapDate = dtpInspectionDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                scrapShift = cbShift.Text;

                PartCode = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                //define each of the counts
                int qtyInspCount = SQLMethods.CountQtyInspTotal(scrapDate, scrapShift, area, PartCode);
                int scrapCount = SQLMethods.CountScrapReworkTotal(scrapDate, scrapShift, area, PartCode, "S");
                int reworkCount = SQLMethods.CountScrapReworkTotal(scrapDate, scrapShift, area, PartCode, "R");

                //populate each of the counts cells
                row.Cells[2].Value = 0;
                row.Cells[5].Value = qtyInspCount;
                row.Cells[3].Value = scrapCount;
                row.Cells[4].Value = reworkCount;
            }

            //format dgv
            //dgvDetials.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true; //sets cell to read only so cannot be edited
            //dgvDetials.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Die Number"; //column header
            //dgvDetials.Columns[0].Width = 80; //column width
            dgvDetials.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
            dgvDetials.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Die Description";
            dgvDetials.Columns[1].Width = 150;
            dgvDetials.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
            dgvDetials.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Part Code";
            dgvDetials.Columns[0].Width = 90;
       //   dgvDetials.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Machine";
       //   dgvDetials.Columns[2].Width = 80;
            dgvDetials.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Quantity Inspected";
            dgvDetials.Columns[2].Width = 90;
            dgvDetials.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
            dgvDetials.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Scrap";
            dgvDetials.Columns[3].Width = 80;
            dgvDetials.Columns[4].ReadOnly = true;
            dgvDetials.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Rework";
            dgvDetials.Columns[4].Width = 80;
            dgvDetials.Columns[5].ReadOnly = true;
            dgvDetials.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Quantity Inspected Recorded";
            dgvDetials.Columns[5].Width = 90;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error retirieving data and setting up grid view. Processed with error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }    //inserts figures into database
string area, inspDate, inspShift, partNo, dieCode, comment, machine;
int qtyInsp;

try
{
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvDetials.Rows) //loop through each of the rows in the dgv
  {
    int intQtyInsp;
    if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[3].Value) == "") //if the machine column is empty
    {
      intQtyInsp = 0; //quantity inspected is 0. Allows for current quantity to be displayed while not reinserting
    }
    else if (row.Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "") //if quantity inspected is empty
    {
      intQtyInsp = 0; //quantity inspected is 0. Prevents null value errors.
    }
    else
    {
      intQtyInsp = Int32.Parse(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString()); //sets quantity inspected to value entered
    }

    if (intQtyInsp == 0) //if quantity inspected is 0. Ignore row.
    {
    }
    else //else gather details and insert row as production.
    {
      area = dtArea.Rows[cbArea.SelectedIndex]["area_code"].ToString();
      inspDate = dtpInspectionDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
      inspShift = cbShift.Text;
      partNo = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
      dieCode = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
      qtyInsp = intQtyInsp;
      comment = "";
      machine = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

      SQLMethods.insertProduction(area, inspDate, inspShift, partNo, dieCode, qtyInsp, comment, machine);
    }
  }

  retrieveData(); //reset values
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Error instering production values. Processed with error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Which cells? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: so basically when i insert a value into the quantity inspected cell this should be calculated in the  quantity inspected recorded cell. this works fine, its just when i edit another cell, all the values in the quantity  inspected  recorded cell change where as only the current cell should change. confusing i know :(

Comment: You're not setting any row values in the code I see. You're only taking values and dumping them into the database.

Comment: what u mean by row values?  i have set the values of my cells

Comment: Your DGV rows aren't being changed in this code- none of the values in any other cells should be effected other than the one you modified.

Comment: It seems that the code you provide is the next step after setting the values of the cells. How do you populate the DataGridView? Could it be that you are reusing the same DataGridViewRow object instead of creating a new one for each row?

Comment: sorry but i dont understand what you mean

Comment: You are looping over the `dgvDetials.Rows`. How did you put the data into that DataGridView? We need to see that code to be able to help you.

Comment: The datagrid is popuated based on the information inserted in another form, and i use drop down boxs to retrieve this information. i have added the rest of the code above..